# How to shrink polygon by a defined amount in centimetres using co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, geometry, vector-graphics

I am trying to shrink a polygon by a specific amount where all edges in the new polygon are of equal distance to the old one. To explain better I have a picture here.

[image: example of scenario]

If the picture doesnt work I have a link here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNWmI.jpg

This is a rough drawing.

I have a point array in ([x,y]) 
[[390,435], [388,430], [391,425], [425,428], [410,435]]

I am trying to shrink it so the new array 
[[x1,y1], [x2,y2] ... [x5,y5]]

ensures that the distance between the new area and the original one is 2 at all sides of the area.

How can I do this by only manipulating the co-ordinates. I know I need some kind of scalar vector but I'm unsure how to do this. I am trying to implement this in javascript

Comment: Is your polygon always convex? Is it OK that the reduced polygon might have fewer sides when you  apply that logic?

Comment: yes it is always convex, the number of sides doesnt matter as long as the area is always 2 less that the original at all points

Comment: This problem does not have much to do with programming, might be a better fit for [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ok I apologise I will ask maths first to get a conceptual idea first too see if I can implement it myself, I'm just a bit stumped

Comment: Would it be easier if it was a rectangle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420003/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done some research because there is lots of topics in internet about that subject, the short answer is **this is not easy** because there is lots of edge cases ([look this topic for exemple](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150068/shrink-polygon-to-a-specific-area-by-offsetting)).

A good term if you want to look more and find nice libs to do this task for your is Polygon offsetting

**Others good links :**

- [An algorithm for inflating/deflating (offsetting, buffering) polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons)
- [ClipperOffset](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Classes/ClipperOffset/_Body.htm)
- [A Survey of Polygon Offseting Strategies](http://fcacciola.50webs.com/Offseting%20Methods.htm)
- [Javascript Clipper](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/documentation/?version=84)

Comment: I did a little but not enough clearly, thanks for your answer the links are very good :)

Answer (score 3):

In the general case this is indeed an arduous problem. But for a convex polygon, it is pretty easy.

At every angle, draw the bissector and find the point at distance of the vertex equal to `d / sin α/2` where `α` is the measure of the angle.

[image]

Comment: What about shrinking a concave polygon?

Comment: @IvanZ: depends if it self-intersects or not.

Comment: A polygon is without self-intersection. Do you have any suggestions for this case?

Comment: @IvanZ: I mean after shrinking.

Comment: Yes, its edges may intersect. How to identify and collapse such edges?

Comment: @IvanZ: you need a polygon handling software with union capability.